# Date / Time showing odd value in PHP

Tags: php, date, formatting

I have wierd issues with time / date in PHP this year. Code have not changed at all and my dates are bugged.

Code is for example:

```
$date = strtotime($order['date']);

$dateNew = date('Y-m-d h:i A', $date);

print $dateNew;
```

Returns `1969-12-31 07:00 PM` for some reasson, altough:

```
print $order['date'];
```

Returns `2013-01-12 18:25:43`

I'm confused because I'm quite sure that my code is correct.

I dare you to solve this bugger!

Comment: `$order['date']` appears twice. Which one does the second block refer to? Maybe we should just give them different names for this question.

Comment: Works on my box, too. Sounds like there's some code somewhere else that's messing up. (Never assert that your code is certainly correct :P)

Comment: Have you checked to see what gets returned with strtotime?  Sounds like something else is up with the initial date format.  I would try to output quotes around it and see if there are extra characters.

Comment: what is the vale of $order['date'] in the first example

Comment: Here too http://codepad.viper-7.com/cyXGKd

Comment: `var_dump($order['date']);` instead of `print $order['date'];` to be sure about input.

Comment: [Here's me running your exact code with the expected input, and it works fine.](http://codepad.org/afDXPedJ) I suspect `$order['date']` doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: File is quite big, arround 3000 lines, I'll check if this variables ($order['date'] or $date) are perhaps overwriten somehow or something, because var_dump($order['date']) and print $order['date'] returns proper date atleast.

Comment: Here's mine version, failing: http://codepad.viper-7.com/V8brIT Answer for it is to validate input. (like here there is no-breaking space instead of normal one)

Comment: @Adrov I had some precisions in my answer after digging more your problem, hope it helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function strtotime() was made for transform English into date format.

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

As i don't know what is really into your $order variable i will suggest 2 solutions :

Maybe you can avoid the strtotime function and replace it by date() directly like this :

```
$order = ['date' => '2013-01-12 18:25:43'];
$date = date($order['date']);
```

It works well here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/cbNA87

Or, if it's not working consider to use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), it will convert the date into seconds since the epoch.

The Unix epoch is the reference point for all time stamps. PHP calculates the times from this date in seconds.
The `$date` should be null and your server in the east coast of the US so it's returns the epoch :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP returns the date 1969-12-31 when there is not a proper date. So if you did

```
$date = 0;
$dateNew = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Your result would be 1969-12-31, since that is the default Unix epoch time. http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 1):

Unexpected dates of "1969-12-31 07:00 PM" means something went wrong with date() .

your strototime($order['date']) is probably returning false (failing to parse it to a unix timestamp).

Try this and ensure its returning an int (not false)

```
 var_dump($order['date'], strtotime($order['date']));
```

See the error state of date: http://php.net/date
See the return values of strtotime: http://php.net/strtotime